# FusionChart; Remove color range slider from map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, fusioncharts

Please, how can I remove colour range slider from fusion chart? I have tried to remove the `colorrange` from the `chart` object but it is stil there.

Thanks

Comment: to remove the color range slider set showLegend attribute at the chart level as 0, here is a demo - http://jsfiddle.net/n06aqv3h/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your dataSource colorrange object, set "gradient" to 0

```
"colorrange": {
    "gradient": 0,
    "color": [
      {
        "minvalue": "0",
        "maxvalue": "50",
        "code": "#62B58F"
      },
      {
        "minvalue": "50",
        "maxvalue": "75",
        "code": "#FFC533"
      },
      {
        "minvalue": "75",
        "maxvalue": "100",
        "code": "#F2726F"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove the legend you can use **"showLegend": "0",** at chart level
Refer [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wob17a9y/)

To remove color range slider you can use **"gradient": 0,** at color range level

```
"colorrange": {
       "gradient": 0,
        "color": [{
            "minvalue": "0",
            "maxvalue": "40000000",
            "displayvalue": "Low (<$40M)",
            "code": "#e44a00"
          },
          {
            "minvalue": "40000000",
            "maxvalue": "65000000",
            "displayvalue": "Moderate ($40M - $65M)",
            "code": "#f8bd19"
          },
          {
            "minvalue": "65000000",
            "maxvalue": "97400000",
            "displayvalue": "High($65M+)",
            "code": "#6baa01"
          }
        ]
      },
```

Refer the demo [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wob17a9y/1/)